# Windows Azure Cloud App - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure, ssl

I am trying to pull JSON from a customer's website, but I get this error.

1. The code works my local machine.
2. For other sites, both on my local machine and on the server, the code works.
3. The site is https://www.vapedepot.ca/wc-api/v1

Does he have a special SSL cert where I need to change my code? Here is my code:

```
    string GetJson(string url)
    {
        string resultData = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 6000;
        //myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string userP = m_UserName + ":" + m_Password;
        byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userP).ToArray();
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes));
        WebResponse httpResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        resultData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        responseStream.Close();
        httpResponse.Close();
        return resultData;
    }
```

He is using CloudFlare and the SSL uses ecdsa.

Comment: I have the same problem with calling a Cloudflare SSL endpoint from Azure? Have you found the root cause?

Comment: Yes, I did. Cloudflare is using a shared SSL certificate and many sites have the same SSL. You need a dedicated IP and a dedicated SSL certificate.

Comment: .NET should support SNI without problems, why is that an issue on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I swapped to using RestSharp to make my secure web requests and it resolved my issue.